# What is default session timeout in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout, asp.net-2.0

What is the default session timeout value in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 107):

It is 20 Minutes according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.80).aspx)

From MSDN:

> Optional TimeSpan attribute.
>
> Specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is abandoned. The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and state-server modes.
> The session timeout configuration setting applies only to ASP.NET pages. Changing the session timeout value does not affect the session time-out for ASP pages. Similarly, changing the session time-out for ASP pages does not affect the session time-out for ASP.NET pages.
> **The default is 20 minutes.**

Answer (score 48):

**It depends on either the *configuration* or *programmatic change***.
Therefore the most reliable way to check the current value is at *runtime* via code.

See the **[HttpSessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)** property; default value is 20 minutes.

You can access this propery in ASP.NET via [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx):

```
this.HttpContext.Session.Timeout // ASP.NET MVC controller
Page.Session.Timeout // ASP.NET Web Forms code-behind
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout // Elsewhere
```

Comment: i am able to get the value 20 while checking `int check = this.HttpContext.Session.Timeout;` but can i set session timeout with key ? and check session timeout for particular key like: `Session["mykey"]` ?

Comment: for those of you who didn't click the MSDN link, the `Timeout` property value is in minutes

Answer (score 38):

1. The Default Expiration Period for **Session is 20 Minutes**.
2. The Default Expiration Period for **Cookie is 30 Minutes**.
3. Maximum Size of **ViewState is 25% of Page Size**

Answer (score 26):

The default is 20 minutes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.80).aspx

```
<sessionState 
mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
timeout="number of minutes"
cookieName="session identifier cookie name"
cookieless=
     "[true|false|AutoDetect|UseCookies|UseUri|UseDeviceProfile]"
regenerateExpiredSessionId="[True|False]"
sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
sqlCommandTimeout="number of seconds"
allowCustomSqlDatabase="[True|False]"
useHostingIdentity="[True|False]"
stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"
customProvider="custom provider name">
<providers>...</providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: This code goes in the <system.web> section of the web.config file

Answer (score 4):

The Default Expiration Period for Session is 20 Minutes.

You can update sessionstate and configure the minutes under timeout

```
<sessionState 
timeout="30">
</sessionState>
```

Comment: This code goes in the <system.web> section of the web.config file